# Xcode 6.2 on El capitane - Storyboard compiler error: Exception while running ibtool

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, osx-elcapitan

I have a project that is build in **Swift 1**, so thats why I am still using **Xcode 6.2**. (I cannot migrate, because there is too much code, and after I still tried to fix all the errors, the app started crashing).

Everything worked fine, until I upgraded to **OS X El Capitane**. Now I can't even compile my app anymore. It throws this error:

> **Interface Builder Storyboard Compiler Error**
>
> /Users/.../Main.storyboard: Exception while running ibtool:
> -[IBUIViewControllerAutolayoutGuide shouldBeArchived]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffb1609f520

I am aware of the Xcode 6.x issues on El Capitane but I **really** need this to get it working.

I tried to everything I found about the issues with Xcode 6.x and OS X El Capitan.

Comment: update your Xcode and everything will be fine

Comment: I cannot upgrade it, because I use Swift 1, and Xcode 7 uses Swift 2, which means thousands of errors...

Comment: i don't know there is other solution or not...but I think you need to update it for this working...wait for others response

Comment: Update now, it will only be more difficult later and eventually you will have to.

Comment: @DejanSkledar, Xcode 7 has tooling to update your swift code to Swift 2. Don't let that stop you from an upgrade plus it's best to move to the latest version of the language anyway since it is still evolving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've to stick with a prior version of OS X to make this work. The previous versions of Xcode 6.1.x and 6.2.x are not compatible with ElCapitan.

Comment: I know that officially it isn't supported.. Just looking checking some tweaks that may help.

Comment: There's no hack so far. (as far as I know). The interface builder is crashy. (not sure if copying Xcode 7's would work)

Answer (score 0):

Just update the Xcode to the recent version and it will work perfectly.
Even I had the problem, upgrading solved the problem. Did you upgrade?